# If descriptions can be objective, then can prescriptions be objective too?

Tags: ethics, nihilism, objectivity

I don't get the whole "prescriptions can't be objective" argument from nihilists. If something as subjective as a human's description of a flower can be considered as objective according to those same nihilists, then so too can prescriptions.

Comment: which [moral skeptics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-moral/) are you talking about? the argument you give seems to be an uninteresting variant of "why be moral", uninteresting as it just states its conclusion (there's no reason for me)

Comment: i think the question is bad. it's unclear what argument or counter-argument you mean. the idea seems to be that many things some people think of as subjective are objective, that's a very bad argument tho. i could reply that some unnamed people think that something is objective, perhaps their feelings about pictures of flowers, but they are in fact subjective

Comment: What was the answer?